# dispatching keyboard event does nothing in Jest test environment

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, jsdom

I am trying to simulate keystrokes to an input box in one of my Jest tests.

This code works perfectly well in a browser, but doesn't seem to do anything in my test, no errors. I think I'm missing something obvious here, any pointers?

The reason for doing keystrokes is because I want to test the focus of an input after X characters, so any other ideas of how to test this in Jest would also be appreciated.

```
const key1 = document.querySelector('.test-input');

console.log('before', key1.value); // "" empty

key1.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { 'key': 'a' }));
key1.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { 'key': 'b' }));
key1.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { 'key': 'c' }));

console.log('after', key1.value); // "" empty

key1.value = 'hello??';

console.log('after', key1.value); // "hello??"
```

Comment: How are you testing it? Please consider that Jest uses [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) to mock browser environment.

Comment: Node environment using Jest. I have a bunch of other tests that are fine, just seems to be the keyboard event that I'm having issues with. I have no assertions yet, just trying to grab an updated value after the keystrokes, then will make assertions.

Comment: Maybe you need to trigger keypress as well? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that I needed to programatically focus on the input first!